# Shipping Cost and Tax not working after installing amazon payments extension in magento2.2.4?

Tags: admin, magento2.2.4

I have to enable amazon payments module and if I enable this module shipping cost and tax are not displaying at the one step checkout page. I don't know how to implement this task. Please find this link https://prnt.sc/kwwn90 Could you please help me?